# How to extract not indexed array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, json, type-conversion

I have an array with this structure when I print_r() my json input with method post

```
 public function ajax_add($mode) {
    echo "<pre>";      
      print_r($this->input->post());
   echo "</pre>";
 }
```

this is my print_r result

```
    Array

(
    [{"thang":"2019","kd_kegiatan":"2409","kd_output":"014","kd_sub_output":"002","kd_komponen":"307","kd_sub_komponen":"B","nama_sub_komponen":"","kd_dept":"033","kd_unit":"04","kd_program":"08","id_paket":""}] => 
    [0] => 
)
```

I need to convert json data above to assosiative array
for example

```
array(

   "thang"=>2019,
   "kd_kegiatan"=>2409
   "kd_output"=>014,
   "etc"=>"....."
)
```

but I don't know to doing that. because the first array have no index. how to fix that?

Comment: So you want to convert it into `Map` instead of `Array` I guess?

Comment: just like my example above.
the important thing is I can extract to particulary data.
actualy i don't need index[0] from my print_r() result

Comment: to doing that I am already doing this
print_r($this->input->post()[1]);
but I get no result